# Pytest with argparse: how to test user is prompted for confirmation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, argparse

I have a CLI tool, and would like to test that the user is prompted to confirm a choice using `input()`. This would be equivalent as using `raw_input()` in Python 2.

#### Code

The (paraphrased) code to test looks like:

```
import sys
import argparse


def confirm():
    notification_str = "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'"
    while True:
        choice = input("Confirm [Y/n]?").lower()
        if choice in 'yes' or not choice:
            return True
        if choice in 'no':
            return False
        print(notification_str)


def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--destructive', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    if args.destructive:
        if not confirm():
            sys.exit()
    do_stuff(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Question

I am using pytest as my framework. How do I make it so I can test that the confirmation prompt is showing up in the CLI? If I try to compare `stdout` I get the error: `OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured`.

I want to make sure that:

1. The confirmation shows up when the destructive flag is set
2. It doesn't show up when it isn't

I will be using the following code in another file:

```
import pytest
from module_name import main


def test_user_is_prompted_when_destructive_flag_is_set():
    sys.argv['', '-d']
    main()
    assert _  # What the hell goes here?


def test_user_is_not_prompted_when_destructive_flag_not_set():
    sys.argv['',]
    main()
    assert _  # And here too?
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. To be clear, I don't want to test/mock the user's input, I want to make sure that the question is asked. I'll change the title to better reflect this.

Comment: The mock library has methods to determine how many times the mock is invoked. That is how you tell it was called.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest that starting testing with the `confirm()` function is a better unit test strategy. This allows things like `input` and `sys.stdio` to be mocked more locally.  Then once assured confirms works as expected, tests can be written that verify that it is called in specific ways. You can write tests for that, and mock `confirm()` during those tests.

Here is a unit test for`confirm()` that uses [`pytest.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) and [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html) to deal with user input and output:

#### Code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("from_user, response, output", [
    (['x', 'x', 'No'], False, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n" * 2),
    ('y', True, ''),
    ('n', False, ''),
    (['x', 'y'], True, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n"),
])
def test_get_from_user(from_user, response, output):
    from_user = list(from_user) if isinstance(from_user, list) else [from_user]

    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda x: from_user.pop(0)):
        with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO):
            assert response == confirm()
            assert output == sys.stdout.getvalue()
```

#### How does this work?

`pytest.mark.parametrize` allows a test function to be easily called multple times with conditions.  Here are 4 simple steps which will test most of the functionality in `confirm`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("from_user, response, output", [
    (['x', 'x', 'No'], False, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n" * 2),
    ('y', True, ''),
    ('n', False, ''),
    (['x', 'y'], True, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n"),
])
```

[`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) can be used to temporarily replace a function in module (among other uses).  In this case it is used to replace `input` and `sys.stdout` to allow inject user input, and capture printed strings

```
with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda x: from_user.pop(0)):
    with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO):
```

finally the function under test is run and the output of the function and any string printed are verified:

```
assert response == confirm()
assert output == sys.stdout.getvalue()
```

#### Test Code (for the test code):

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
import pytest
from unittest import mock
import builtins

def confirm():
    notification_str = "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'"
    while True:
        choice = input("Confirm [Y/n]?").lower()
        if choice in 'yes' or not choice:
            return True
        if choice in 'no':
            return False
        print(notification_str)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("from_user, response, output", [
    (['x', 'x', 'No'], False, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n" * 2),
    ('y', True, ''),
    ('n', False, ''),
    (['x', 'y'], True, "Please respond with 'y' or 'n'\n"),
])
def test_get_from_user(from_user, response, output):
    from_user = list(from_user) if isinstance(from_user, list) \
        else [from_user]
    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda x: from_user.pop(0)):
        with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO):
            assert response == confirm()
            assert output == sys.stdout.getvalue()

pytest.main('-x test.py'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: C:\Users\stephen\Documents\src\testcode, inifile:
collected 4 items

test.py ....                                                             [100%]

========================== 4 passed in 0.15 seconds ===========================
```

#### Test Calls to `confirm()`:

To test that confirm is called when expected, and that the program responds as expected when called, you can use `unittest.mock` to mock `confirm()`.

Note: In the usual unittest scenario, `confirm` would be in a different file and `mock.patch` could be used in a similiar manner to how `sys.argv` is patched in this example.

#### Test Code for checking calls to `confirm()`:

```
import sys
import argparse

def confirm():
    pass

def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--destructive', action='store_true')
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    if args.destructive:
        if not confirm():
            sys.exit()


import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.mark.parametrize("argv, called, response", [
    ([], False, None),
    (['-d'], True, False),
    (['-d'], True, True),
])
def test_get_from_user(argv, called, response):
    global confirm
    original_confirm = confirm
    confirm = mock.Mock(return_value=response)
    with mock.patch('sys.argv', [''] + argv):
        if called and not response:
            with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
                main()
        else:
            main()

        assert confirm.called == called
    confirm = original_confirm

pytest.main('-x test.py'.split())
```

#### Results:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: C:\Users\stephen\Documents\src\testcode, inifile:
collected 3 items

test.py ...                                                              [100%]

========================== 3 passed in 3.26 seconds ===========================
enter code here
```