# how to pass command line argument from pytest to code

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, argparse

I am trying to pass arguments from a pytest testcase to a module being tested. For example, using the main.py from [Python boilerplate](https://www.python-boilerplate.com/py3+argparse+pytest), I can run it from the command line as:

```
$ python3 main.py
usage: main.py [-h] [-f] [-n NAME] [-v] [--version] arg
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: arg
$ python3 main.py xx
hello world
Namespace(arg='xx', flag=False, name=None, verbose=0)
```

Now I am trying to do the same with pytest, with the following test_sample.py

(**NOTE:** the main.py requires command line arguments. But these arguments need to be hardcoded in a specific test, they should not be command line arguments to pytest. The pytest testcase only needs to send these values as command line arguments to main.main().)

```
import main
def test_case01():
    main.main()
    # I dont know how to pass 'xx' to main.py,
    # so for now I just have one test with no arguments
```

and running the test as:

```
pytest -vs test_sample.py
```

This fails with error messages. I tried to look at other answers for a solution but could not use them. For example, [42778124](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778124) suggests to create a separate file run.py which is not a desirable thing to do. And [48359957](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359957) and [40880259](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259) seem to deal more with command line arguments for pytest, instead of passing command line arguments to the main code.

I dont need the pytest to take command line arguments, the arguments can be hardcoded inside a specific test. But these arguments need to be passed as arguments to the main code. Can you give me a test_sample.py, that calls main.main() with some arguments?

Comment: you could use monkeypatching. `def test_case01(monkeypatch): with monkeypatch.context() as m: m.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['my', 'dummy', 'args']); main()`. Inside the context block, the `sys.argv` list is monkeypatched with your values.

Comment: Which are you testing - commandline interface, or the code behind it - the functions and classes that use the parsed `args`?

Comment: @hpaulj: I am testing the functions that use the parsed args.

Comment: @hoefling: I have accepted another answer, which is working for me with minimal code changes. But I did not understand your comment, would it be possible for you to add a detailed answer, so that maybe I can use your solution later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice might to have this kind of code, instead of reading arguments from main method.

```
# main.py
def main(arg1):
    return arg1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My awesome script')
    parser.add_argument('word', help='a word')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.word)
```

This way, your main method can easily be tested in pytest

```
import main
def test_case01():
    main.main(your_hardcoded_arg)
```

I am not sure you can call a python script to test except by using `os` module, which might be not a good practice

Comment: For someone else looking into this issue without requiring to get into monkeypatching, [here](http://euccas.github.io/blog/20160807/python-unittest-handle-command-line-arguments.html) is a nice solution as well. By the way, why has this accepted answer been downvoted?

Answer (score 10):

If you can't modify the signature of the `main` method, you can use the  [monkeypatching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) technique to temporarily replace the arguments with the test data. Example: imagine writing tests for the following program:

```
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Greeter')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return f'hello {args.name}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

When running it from the command line:

```
$ python greeter.py world
hello world
```

To test the `main` function with some custom data, monkeypatch `sys.argv`:

```
import sys
import greeter

def test_greeter(monkeypatch):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['greeter', 'spam'])
        assert greeter.main() == 'hello spam'
```

When combined with the [parametrizing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) technique, this allows to easily test different arguments without modifying the test function:

```
import sys
import pytest
import greeter

@pytest.mark.parametrize('name', ['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon'])
def test_greeter(monkeypatch, name):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['greeter', name])
        assert greeter.main() == 'hello ' + name
```

Now you get three tests, one for each of the arguments:

```
$ pytest -v test_greeter.py

...

test_greeter.py::test_greeter[spam] PASSED
test_greeter.py::test_greeter[eggs] PASSED
test_greeter.py::test_greeter[bacon] PASSED
```